# Loop through tr element in Backbone $el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've set the `el` in my view to be a specific table, and now I'd like to loop through that table, row by row, and update the second and third `td` elements.

Below is my most recent attempt (the `updateCalc` method is where I'm working). First time using Backbone so any words of wisdom are more than welcome.

```
var IndexedView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (args) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'updateCalc')
        _.bindAll(this, 'updateAllocation');

        //Bind modle change event to view event handler
        this.model.bind('change:purchasePayment', this.updateAllocation);
        this.model.bind('change:slidervalue', this.updateAllocation);            
        this.model.bind('change:purchasePayment', this.updateCalc);
        this.model.bind('change:slidervalue', this.updateCalc);
        this.model.bind('change:fixedRate', this.updateCalc);
        this.model.bind('change:returnSpx', this.updateCalc);           
    },
   el: $('#IndexedTable'),  

   //TRYING TO LOOP THROUGH TABLE HERE
   updateCalc: function () {
       //Illust = Allocation * (1 + spx)^cap hit
       //Guar = Allocation * (1 + 0)^cap hit
       var spx = this.model.get('returnSpx');

       this.$el.find('tbody tr').each(function (key, row) {
           console.log(row);
           var capHit = 1;//row.find('td.capHit');
           var illust = this.$el.find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow((1 + spx), capHit);
           var guar = this.$el.find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow(1, capHit);
           this.children().eq(1).text(value)
           this.children().eq(2).text(value)
       });
   },
   updateAllocation: function () {
       var value = this.model.get('purchasePayment') * $('#sliderVal').val();
       this.$el.find('td#allocation').text(value);
   }
});
```

**HTML**

```
            <table id="IndexedTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Indexed
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Allocation
                        </td>
                        <td id="allocation">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cap hits:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Illust
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Guar
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="capHit">
                            0
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="capHit">
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="capHit">
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
             </table>
```

Here is the error message I'm getting

[image]

Comment: $(this.el).find() use this..

Comment: what about:``this.el.find('tr')``

Comment: use that for the `.each` or inside to get the `td` element?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - that comes up `undefined` and I can't loop through `el`

Comment: Your backbone view doesn't have a `render` function. Did you not paste it here? Can you do that please?

Comment: There is no `render` function. I'm amending to this example: https://gist.github.com/karthikshiraly/1593688

Comment: You gotta add the `render` function. Without it you're just creating an instance of the view without doing anything with it. The `render` function is the heart of the views. Something like this: `render: function() {  this.$el.html('#IndexedTable');  }`. In this case you have to specify `el` as a container, like a `div` or the `body`. And by the way why are you not using the official backbone documentation? The example on github makes not guarantee that of the correctness of the examples. Maybe try this: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/

Comment: @Hamid - the `updateAllocation` works fine though. Is the `render` necessary to loop through the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
updateCalc: function () {
       //Illust = Allocation * (1 + spx)^cap hit
       //Guar = Allocation * (1 + 0)^cap hit
       var spx = this.model.get('returnSpx');
       // Tie this to that, so you can use it in your function
       var that = this;

       this.$el.find('tbody tr').each(function (key, row) {
           console.log(row); // row refers to your HTML element
           var $row = $(row); // $row will refer to your jQuery object
           var capHit = $row.find('td.capHit').text();
           var illust = that.$el.find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow((1 + spx), capHit);
           var guar = that.$el.find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow(1, capHit);
           $row.children().eq(1).text(value)
           $row.children().eq(2).text(value)
       });
   },
```

The first problem that you're having is that you're treating an HTML element as a jQuery object, which is why you're getting your error in the console.

The second problem is that `this` is also referencing your html element and not your backbone `this`. In order to fix that, you can tie `this` to `that` and then use that.

You can also use the underscore function `_.bind` to bind `this` to your Backbone view.

```
updateCalc: function () {
       //Illust = Allocation * (1 + spx)^cap hit
       //Guar = Allocation * (1 + 0)^cap hit
       var spx = this.model.get('returnSpx');

       this.$el.find('tbody tr').each(_.bind(function (key, row) {
           console.log(row); // row refers to your HTML element
           var $row = $(row); // $row will refer to your jQuery object
           var capHit = $row.find('td.capHit').text();
           var illust = this.$el.find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow((1 + spx), capHit);
           var guar = this.$el.find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow(1, capHit);
           $row.children().eq(1).text(value)
           $row.children().eq(2).text(value)
       }, this));
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hamil's comment this is probably a hack, but I got it to work. If someone has a better answer will gladly accept.

```
   updateCalc: function () {
       //Illust = Allocation * (1 + spx)^cap hit
       //Guar = Allocation * (1 + 0)^cap hit
       var spx = this.model.get('returnSpx');
       this.$el.find('tbody tr').each(function () {
           var capHit = $(this).find('td:first').text();
           var illust = $('#IndexedTable').find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow((1 + spx), capHit);
           var guar = $('#IndexedTable').find('td#allocation').text() * Math.pow(1, capHit);

           $(this).children().eq(1).text(illust);
           $(this).children().eq(2).text(guar);
       });
   },
```